# Confidence Interval for Random Set Coverage

Tags: distributions, python, confidence-interval

**Question:**

If I pick n random integers from the range [0:m-1], what is x such that I have a 95% chance of picking x or more unique values?

How do I generalize this to create a 99% one sided confidence interval?

(Each pick has a uniform 1/m chance of picking each integer in the range)

**My Attempt (WRONG):**

Odds of picking value i on one read: `1/m`

Odds of not picking value i on one read: `(m-1)/m`

Odds of not picking value i on n reads: `((m-1)/m)^n`

Expected number of unique values:
`coverage = m * (1 - ((m-1)/m)^n)`

Up to this point seems to be right based on empirical tests.

To build the confidence interval, I assume all m values in the range have the same independent chance of being chosen on each read (WRONG), and use the binomial distribution.

```
from scipy.stats import binom
n,p = m, coverage
mean, var, skew, kurt = binom.stats(n,p, moments='mvsk')
min_bound, max_bound = binom.interval(0.95,n,p)
```

This ever so slightly inflates the 95% confidence interval, such that nearly all of my empirical tests end up inside the interval.
What distribution am I supposed to be using here instead?
How can I calculate a one sided interval for this distribution (since python can only do a 2 sided one)

**Why?:**

I'm building a model for genome read coverage and I need to create a lower bound for percentage of genome (of length g) covered given n reads of length k.

Rather than trying to compute it directly, I'm using this simplification:

Divide the genome into m=g/k buckets, each of length ~k.  Assume each read covers exactly 1 bucket.

Comment: When you say, "pick n random numbers from the range [0:m-1]," do you mean integers?  That appears to be the case based on your referencing the binomial distribution, but I want to make sure I understand the question correctly.  It is important to know what you are sampling from.  In your problem statement you assumed that all the numbers in the range are equally likely, which to me suggests a discrete uniform distribution.

Comment: A confidence interval is used to make inference on an unknown parameter in the probability model.  If the data are discrete uniform and $m$ is known there is no confidence interval to construct.  You would simply calculate a probability under the known (or assumed) probability model.  If $m$ is unknown then you could construct a confidence interval for this.

Comment: @GeoffreyJohnson m, n and x are all known (and are >100000).  I have a recurrence relation that gives an exact pdf, but I don't have a closed form solution for it (so it takes hours to calculate and it might not be exactly binomial), I'm trying to get the one tail bound for the coverage (x/m) such that 5% of trials have lower coverage than that.